# ' Cannot find module './admin.service' when importing the admin.service.ts file in angular?

Tags: angular

when i try to import the adminservice.ts file to my login component, it is showing error as ' Cannot find module './admin.service'.

admin.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminService } from './admin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css'],
  providers: [ AdminService ]
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

admin.service.ts

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){

  }

  validateLogin(){

  }
}
```

my error:
[image]

Comment: is the file name `adminservice.ts` or `admin.service.ts`?

Comment: admin.service.ts

Comment: is the file in the same folder as the component?

Comment: yes both are in the app/pages folder

Comment: i will upload the service code now

Comment: what version of angular are you using? please edit your question

Comment: i edited the question now.plz chck

Comment: you still havent added the admin.service code

Comment: angular 6 version

Comment: yes  i added please check the question

Comment: no, you added what looks to be a testing file

Comment: sorry my mistake

Comment: it should just be `@Injectable()`

Comment: plz check now, i had changed the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179458/discussion-between-liza-and-mast3rd3mon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change service path :

```
import { AdminService } from './../admin.service';
```